# How do I extract certain information from an API and return as a list in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, api, loops

I'm trying to extract just the "dba" values in the hash from the API and return them as a numbered list.

Here are my 3 separate files/classes. In the 'menu' method I can return all of the hashes, but I just want the "dba" or "restaurant name" instead.

I know I have to put an .each.with_index method in there somewhere, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Any thoughts?

```
class OpenDataAPI
    def self.get_data
        response = HTTParty.get('https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/43nn-pn8j.json')
        response[0..24].each do |hash| 
            RestaurantInspections.new(hash)
        end
    end
end
```

```
class CLI
    def begin
        OpenDataAPI.get_data
        puts "Welcome to the Restaurant Inspection CLI!"
        menu
    end

    def menu
        input = nil
        while input != "exit"
        puts "Type 1 for a list of Restaurants, type Exit to exit the program"
        input = gets.strip.downcase
        case input
        when "1"
            puts OpenDataAPI.get_data
            #puts RestaurantInspections.all.each.with_index do |key, index|
            #puts "#{index + 1}: #{key}"
        #end
        when "exit"
            break
        else
            puts "Invalid entry - Please type either 1 or Exit"
        end
    end
    end
```

```
class RestaurantInspections

    attr_reader :restaurant_name, :type_of_food, :violation_description, :grade

    @@all = []

    def initialize(api_hash)
        @restaurant_name = api_hash["dba"]
        @type_of_food = api_hash["cuisine_description"]
        @violation_description = api_hash["violation_description"]
        @grade = api_hash["grade"]
        @@all << self
    end

    def self.all
        @@all
    end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there, just change this method to this:

```
def menu
  input = nil
  while input != "exit"
    puts "Type 1 for a list of Restaurants, type Exit to exit the program"
    input = gets.strip.downcase
    case input
    when "1"
      RestaurantInspections.all.each.with_index do |restaurant, index|
        puts "#{index + 1}: #{restaurant.restaurant_name}"
      end
    when "exit"
      break
    else
      puts "Invalid entry - Please type either 1 or Exit"
    end
  end
end
```